# MySQL join and COUNT() on multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sum, left-join

I'm trying to `COUNT()` on multiple tables in one query, but I can't get it to work. Here's what I have so far:

TABLES:

```
table1
---------------------
id | name
---------------------
 1 | test
 2 | test2


table2
---------------------
id | table1_id
---------------------
 1 | 1
 2 | 1
 3 | 1


table3
---------------------
id | table2_id
---------------------
 1 | 1


table4
---------------------
id | size | table3_id
---------------------
 1 | 1024 | 1
 1 | 200  | 1
```

SQL:

```
SELECT
    table1.name,
    COUNT(table2.table1_id) AS table2_count,
    COUNT(table3.table2_id) AS table3_count,
    COUNT(table4.table3_id) AS table4_count,
    SUM(table4.size) AS table4_size
FROM
    table1
LEFT JOIN table2
    ON table1.id = table2.table1_id
LEFT JOIN table3
    ON table2.id = table3.table2_id
LEFT JOIN table4
    ON table3.id = table4.table3_id
WHERE
    table1.id = 1
```

Results I'm getting from the above query:

```
name | table2_count | table3_count | table4_count | table4_size
---------------------------------------------------------------
test |      4       |      2       |      2       |    1224
```

**Results that I should be getting:**

```
name | table2_count | table3_count | table4_count | table4_size
---------------------------------------------------------------
test |      3       |      1       |      2       |    1224
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need to use `DISTINCT`, but also you need to count the IDs, not the foreign keys:

```
SELECT
    table1.name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT table2.id) AS table2_count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT table3.id) AS table3_count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT table4.id) AS table4_count,
    SUM(table4.size) AS table4_size
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table1_id
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table2.id = table3.table2_id
LEFT JOIN table4 ON table3.id = table4.table3_id
WHERE table1.id = 1
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f23034/8).

**Explanation:** The `DISTINCT` key word eliminates all duplicate values resulting in a list of unique values.

If you run your query without the `COUNT()` and `SUM()`, you get:

```
name  table1_id  table2_id  table3_id  size
test  1          1          1          1024 
test  1          1          1          200 
test  1          (null)     (null)     (null) 
test  1          (null)     (null)     (null)
```

So if you add the `COUNT()` and `SUM()`, you obviously get:

```
name  table1_id  table2_id  table3_id  size
test  4          2          2          1224
```

However, using `DISTINCT` with your query won't help because you can clearly see the duplicate values, which will result in:

```
name  table1_id  table2_id  table3_id  size
test  1          1          1          1224
```

Now, if you run my query without the `COUNT()` and `SUM()`, you get:

```
name  table1_id  table2_id  table3_id  size
test  1          1          1          1024 
test  1          1          2          200 
test  2          (null)     (null)     (null) 
test  3          (null)     (null)     (null)
```

If you add the `COUNT()` and `SUM()`, you get exactly the same results like your query:

```
name  table1_id  table2_id  table3_id  size
test  4          2          2          1224
```

However, because this time you have different values (i.e. not all are 1), so now if you count the unique values using `DISTINCT`, you get:

```
name  table1_id  table2_id  table3_id  size
test  3          1          2          1224
```

Comment: Genius! It worked, can you explain the logic behind it? Thanks!

Comment: I've added a full explanation with examples.

Comment: This is definitely very helpful. Thanks for taking the time to explain all of this. I'll comeback once I'm reputation 15 to upvote you!

Comment: I upvoted your question because it is well structured and you want to understand, not only a copy/paste solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this way

```
SELECT  table1.name,
    (SELECT COUNT(table2.table1_id) WHERE  table1.id = table2.table1_id ) AS table2_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(table3.table2_id) WHERE  table2.id = table3.table1_id ) AS table3_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(table4.table3_id) WHERE  table3.id = table4.table1_id ) AS table4_count,
    (SELECT SUM(table4.size) WHERE  table3.id = table4.table1_id ) AS table4_size
    FROM
    table1
    WHERE
    table1.id = 1
```

Comment: I'm not saving table1 id on table3 nor table4. So, I'll get a syntax error.